# Getting collection of all members of a class

Tags: c#, reflection, member

I want to get the collection of all the members that are present in a class. How do I do that? I am using the following, but it is giving me many extra names along with the members.

```
Type obj  =  objContactField.GetType();
MemberInfo[] objMember = obj.GetMembers();
String name = objMember[5].Name.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you mean you want all methods? Members include things like properties and fields.

Comment: When you write a question, there is preview field below where you can see if things are properly formatted as code etc. I saw that you had tried some formatting, but looking at the preview it didn't show up as code.

Comment: Sanchaita, please accept the answer that worked best for you to properly reward the time the person put into answering. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 19):

Get a collection of all the properties of a class and their values:

```cs
class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Test instance = new Test();
Type type = typeof(Test);

Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
    properties.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(instance));
```

Note that you will need to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` and `using System.Reflection;` for the example to work.

Comment: Yes this is what i am getting

Comment: I've made a short *dotnetfiddle* to demonstrate the usage: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qcWcGA

Comment: This works for properties, but it does not work for ordinary members because MemberInfo does not have a GetValue method.

Answer (score 9):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173113.aspx), members of a class include:

[Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173118.aspx)

[Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173119.aspx) (comes under Fields)

[Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

[Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173114.aspx)

[Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/awbftdfh.aspx)

[Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173145.aspx)

[Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) (comes under Properties)

[Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)

[Destructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)

[Nested Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173120.aspx)

When you do `GetMembers` on a class you get all of these (including static ones defined on the class like static/const/operator, not to mention the instance ones) of that class and the instance members of the classes it inherited (no static/const/operator of base classes) but wouldn't duplicate the overridden methods/properties.

To filter out, you have `GetFields`, `GetProperties`, `GetMethods`, and for greater flexibility, there is `FindMembers`

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends a little on what you get. For example:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Testme t = new Testme();
        Type obj = t.GetType();

        MemberInfo[] objMember = obj.GetMembers();

       foreach (MemberInfo m in objMember)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(m);
       } 
    }


    class Testme
    {
        public String name;
        public String phone;
    }
```

Returns

```
System.String ToString()
Boolean Equals(System.Object)
Int32 GetHashCode()
System.Type GetType()
Void .ctor()
System.String name
System.String phone
```

Which is what I expected, remember, just because your class  inherits from somewhere, there are other things provided by default.

Comment: Yes this is what i am getting

Comment: Int32 GetHashCode()
Void .ctor()
I got these fields along with the proper fields

Comment: But thats exactly what you should!

Comment: An interesting variation of this problem: is there any way of obtaining the second last TestMe class that has been created so far?

Comment: You mean you want to tell what instances of testme have been made and the one before last?

Answer (score 0):

#### [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net) Demo Program

To make it easy to understand what the code from dknaack does i created a [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net) demo program

```
void Main()
{
   User instance = new User();
   Type type = typeof(User);

   Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
         properties.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(instance));
   properties.Dump();    
}

// Define other methods and classes here        
class User
{
    private string foo;
    private string bar { get; set;}
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Dob { get; private set; }
    public static int AddUser(User user)
    {    
        // add the user code
        return 1;
    }
}
```