# How to WriteLine all properties stored in a list with C#?

Tags: c#, class, properties

I have a mini assignment where I have to review the fundamentals of classes and properties. In the context of this code, I am trying to figure out how to print all the properties for each task that is stored in a list.

Here is the code. The commented out code is what I tried so far to print all the properties for each task stored in TaskList.

```
namespace FunProject
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person1 = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Mister",
                LastName = "Programmer",
                Age = 26
            };
            Console.WriteLine(person1.FullName());

            var Task1 = new Task
            {
                TaskName = "read",
                Description = "gain knowledge",
                Id = 1,
                IsDone = true
            };

            var Task2 = new Task
            {
                TaskName = "eat",
                Description = "gain sustenance",
                Id = 2,
                IsDone = false
            };

            person1.TaskList = new List<Task>();
            person1.TaskList.Add(Task1);
            person1.TaskList.Add(Task2);

            //Person1.TaskList.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));

            //Person1.TaskList.ForEach (x => Console.WriteLine(x));

            //Console.WriteLine(String.Join("{0}\t", Person1.TaskList.ToString()));
            //foreach (Task t in Person1.TaskList)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(t);
            //}

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set;}
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<Task>TaskList { get; set; }
        public string FullName()
        {
            return ($"{FirstName} {LastName}");
        }
    }

    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set;}
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool ?IsDone { get; set;}
    }
}
```

Output should be something like:

```
Mister Programmer
Current Tasks:
TaskName: read
TaskDescription: gain knowledge
Id: 1
IsDone: true

TaskName: eat
TaskDescription: gain sustenance
Id: 2
IsDone: false
```

Comment: Take a look at [this to loop through members of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773806/getting-collection-of-all-members-of-a-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resolve this problem what I would do first, I will create  task list something like this:

```
var list = new List<Task>();
list.Add(Task1);
list.Add(Task2);
```

And then I will add this list to the person that you are creating

```
var person1 = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Mister",
                LastName = "Programmer",
                Age = 26,
                TaskList = list
            };
```

So now you have a person with the list of the tasks. Which is everything you need to create for the output.

So for the output you will need to format something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(person1.FirstName +  " "  + person1.LastName);
Console.WriteLine("Current Tasks:");

person1.TaskList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("TaskName:" + " " + 
x.TaskName + "\n" + "TaskDescription:" + " " + x.Description + "\n" + "Id:" + " " + x.Id + "\n" + "IsDone:" + " " + x.IsDone.ToString().ToLower()));

Console.Read();
```

But if you want to have the properties names without writing the properties in the Console.WriteLine("TaskDescription") or etc. and also to get the values for each property from person object, you will need to use System.Reflection:

```
Type t = person1.GetType();

PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
{
    if (!prop.Name.Equals("TaskList"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}: {prop.GetValue(person1)}");

    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var t1 in person1.TaskList)
        {
            foreach (var propTask in t1.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{propTask.Name}: {propTask.GetValue(t1, null).ToString().ToLower()}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [System.Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=net-6.0) for this...

```
foreach (var t in person1.TaskList)
{
    foreach (var prop in t.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}: {prop.GetValue(t, null).ToString()}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```